# Implementing Placeholder solution with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to use one of the IE9 IE8 placeholder solutions, but i have an error showing in IE9 test setup with the code.  The solution i am using is clearly working for many people according to the comments and updates in github, but I have a fundamental problem getting the code recognised.

I have this line in my page header, which should allow me to use jquery.  Indeed i am running other jquery functions and they seem to be working:

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also in the head i have this (again all the other functions in my myjs.js are showing in developer tools and are available as required):

```
<!-- my java code link -->
<script src="/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

The function that i am using for the placeholder solution is this one:

```
placeholderSupport = ("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"));
if (!placeholderSupport) {
    //This browser does not support the placeholder attribute
    //use javascript instead
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() === input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() === '' || input.val() === input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() === input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        })
    });
}
```

The error that i am getting from IE9 developer tools is this:

```
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
```

The error is showing on the line of code that looks like this, specifically the dollar sign:

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
```

From my reading I thought that the $ start was a function of the jquery library, which i beleive to be present and working, but i am obviously missing a trick.  Can anybody help please. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: I tried this one too some weeks ago.  I had exactly the same problem - i.e it didn't solve the placeholder problem in IE9.  Where must i put the code and what do i have to have as a pre-requirement in order to use these fixes please?

Comment: Load jQuery in the head of the document and have the plugin load just before the closing body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, It works IE8+

**UPDATED**: to match all `inputs` and `textarea`

```
// This adds 'placeholder' to the items listed in the jQuery .support object. 
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
    test = document.createElement('input');
    if ('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
});
// This adds placeholder support to browsers that wouldn't otherwise support it. 
$(function () {
    if (!$.support.placeholder) {
        var active = document.activeElement;
        $('input,textarea').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') !== '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('has-placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') !== '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('has-placeholder');
            }
        });
        $('input,textarea').blur();
        $(active).focus();
        $('form:eq(0)').submit(function () {
            $('input.has-placeholder,textarea.has-placeholder').val('');
        });
    }
});
```

Plus **CSS**

```css
.has-placeholder {
    color:#777 /*whatever you like*/
}
```

Comment: Right!!!! Fantastic, thanks.  I have been messing around with this for weeks on and off.  You are the man - thanks a million!  I note that a couple fo the form fields don't work because they are <input type="tel" rather than "text" or <textarea rather than <input, but i will have a play with the css and see what i can come up with.  Thanks again.

Comment: it is only just changing  this: `$(':text')` to `$('input,textarea')`, give a try and tell me.

Comment: By the way if this helped you in a way you are going to use it, mark it as accepted, for further coming users know which was your choice/solution for your problem.

Comment: Ahh - i was changing $(':text') to $(':textarea') and it was not working.  I will now try without the colon.  What is the colon for out of interest?

Comment: It is only to separate each tag(`input` and `textarea`) in this case.

Comment: I see, but i guess that in lines like this:    $('input.has-placeholder').val(''); we can't put more than one type at a time?  I have put a version below that now works for all the elements on my form using your solution, but i'm sure it acn be simplified.  Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79040/discussion-between-dippas-and-donquick).

Comment: you still can use colon to simplify,  so instead of this `$('input.has-placeholder').val('');` you would have something like this: `$('input.has-placeholder, textarea.has-placeholder').val('');` I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code using Dippas' answer with the extras to cover textareas and inputs that have type='tel' rather than type='text'.  This seems to cover everything on my form, but there might be other input types that need adding at other times.  I'm sure that somebody who knows what they are doing can trim this down by sorting out some of the duplicate code.

```
// This adds 'placeholder' to the items listed in the jQuery .support object. 
jQuery(function() {
jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
test = document.createElement('input');
if ('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;});
// This adds placeholder support to browsers that wouldn't otherwise support it. 
$(function() {
if (!$.support.placeholder) {
    var active = document.activeElement;
    $('textarea').focus(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('has-placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('has-placeholder');
        }
    });
    $('textarea').blur();
    $(active).focus();
    $('form:eq(0)').submit(function() {
        $('textarea.has-placeholder').val('');
    });
    $('input').focus(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('has-placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('has-placeholder');
        }
    });
    $('input').blur();
    $(active).focus();
    $('form:eq(0)').submit(function() {
        $('input.has-placeholder').val('');
    });
  }
});
```